# How to setup my own DNS Server on Rackspace

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, domain-name-system

I do not think this is a duplicate question, I think I maybe a little confused.

Let me preface this by saying, I am by no means a server guru, I'm more than happy to edit files, fix errors and "general" things, but I've never had to do this before.

This is for some personal sites.

I own a few websites, and I decided it was time to get a dedi, so I did with Rackspace. For this post, lets assume I have 2 domains:

`mycompany.com`
`myblog.com`

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is setting up nameservers for "mycompany.com". I want to have "ns1.mycompany.com" and "ns2.mycompany.com". So I set the nameservers for "myblog.com" and my website will appear. I've got my server setup using Nginx, and, I can see my test PHP files working. So the environment works.

My domains are registered with namecheap, I think I will need to do something here too?

I've been following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-18-04

I have completed it, but still, it does not work. I'll be honest when I say that I'm confused about what IP's to use. When Rackspace setup the server, they gave me this information:

```
Device Name : v23123213-blahblahblah.com
NAT IP (private) : 122.11.0.88
Primary IP (public) : 82.111.211.88
Subnet Mask (private) : 111.111.111.0
Gateway (private) : 122.11.0.1
DRAC IP: 122.11.1.4
```

I have changed the IP's for obvious reasons. Now, I guess my questions are:

1. Is the guide I'm following the correct guide or should I follow a different one?
2. From that guide, what IP do I use!? They go in to the "private subnet" in that guide, is that my (private) Subnet Mask?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you have only one server, you should not host your own DNS. Reliable DNS requires two or more servers on separate networks.

Comment: Also, I'm a fan of using a protected "stealth master", where all zone management is done. Your authoritative servers, are simply slaves of the stealth master. NOBODY, except for the administrator should be able to connect to the stealth master.

Comment: @guzzijason I am a fan of using distributed version control for zone files. Each authoritative server has a copy of the repository, and each administrator has a copy of the repository. The repository contains zone files as well as a script used to push the zone files to all authoritative servers. Each step of the way the script checks that all authoritative servers are responding to queries and bails if any of them doesn't.

Comment: @guzzijason: You should write an article on that concept. It would make for a very interesting read!

Answer (score 2):

If you have no experience hosting your own name servers than you shouldn't. NameCheap can host your DNS zones. That's the business they're in. They have specific and extensive experience doing this, so let them do it. There's no technical reason that you need to host your own name servers.

So:

NameCheap will host your DNS zones/Name Servers

RackSpace will host your dedicated server.

This dedicated server will host your websites.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to host your own DNS zones, you need at least two DNS servers. Let's give them the IP addresses 203.0.113.53 and 192.0.2.53. They can have any DNS names, so let's use `ns1.mycompany.com` and `ns2.mycompany.com` as you stated.

Now, for each DNS zone (`mycompany.com` and `myblog.com`) we need to specify which  name servers are responsible for the zones. So at your registrar's web portal, you specify for both domain names that you'll be using two name servers (ns1 and ns2). We'll write this down like this:

```
mycompany.com.   NS   ns1.mycompany.com.
                 NS   ns2.mycompany.com.
myblog.com.      NS   ns1.mycompany.com.
                 NS   ns2.mycompany.com.
ns1.mycompany.com.   A   203.0.113.53
ns2.mycompany.com.   A   1920.2.53
```

Remember that we need to enter this information at your registrar for the two domains, i.e. the company where you bought (rented) the domain names. The last two (`A`) records are *glue* records required for the mycompany.com domain.

Next you need to set up those two name servers using BIND or PowerDNS (or any other name server). Let's assume BIND. Apart from the generic BIND configuration you also need to specify a zone for each domain name you own:

```
zone "mycompany.com" {
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/zones/mycompany.com";
};
zone "myblog.com" {
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/zones/myblog.com";
};
```

These files will then contain at least a `SOA`, two `NS` and two `A` records. In addition you can enter extra `A` records for your web server, e.g. if your web site runs on the server with IP address 203.0.113.80, you can enter this information in the respective files:

```
www.mycompany.com.   A   203.0.113.80

www.myblog.com.      A   203.0.113.80
```

All in all, there is quite a lot to configure and to maintain in order to set this up. And it's quite easy to get things wrong if you don't know what you're doing. Also, buying a second VPS just to host your secondary DNS server might be a bit overkill. Better to just host all your DNS stuff at your registrar, NameCheap in this case. This gives you less headaches and better reliability.

PS: That is not the correct guide to use for what you're trying to achieve.